# Finding random numbers and a pattern from them

Tags: java, random

I have a large homework problem and none of my attempts to solve a small part of it work. The project is a game of life, so at each step the organism in a cell has to consider each of its surrounding cells. Diagonals aren't used and I want to start the consideration at a random cell.

I've approached it several ways but I honing in on this as the best.

Part one - find a random x and y that are a side, not a diagonal. I figured that to be a side abs(x) and abs(y) can't be the same. I loop through random tries until the abs()s are different.

Part two - use four if() to determine the current side and then change the x,y to the next side (going clockwise).

My results have been that the loop stops at odd places and never with abs()s different. I suspect the while() expression is wrong. I tried abs(x).equals(abs(y)) but found that method does not work on primitives. So I tried abs(x) != abs(y) but that leads to odd results.

Here is current effort. Any help would be appreciated.

```
   public static void main(String[] args)   {
      //jkbeg
       System.out.println("objective in this section is" +
            " to get a random side and then move clockwise around to others");
       int targetx; //these will hold the next cell to use.
       int targety;

//     Part One - get random side to be starting cell
//     n.b. abs(x) == abs(y) means diagnol cell, not a side
//     first get randoms of 0 or 1 into targets. 
//     keep trying randoms until abs() are not equal       
     do {   
         targetx = (int) (Math.round(Math.random()));
         targety = (int) (Math.round(Math.random()));
         System.out.println("rando, not checked yet"+targetx +","+targety);
         System.out.println("abs x "+Math.abs(targetx));
         System.out.println("abs y "+Math.abs(targetx));
     }while(Math.abs(targetx) == (Math.abs(targety))  );
     System.out.println("after check for sides, not corners"+targetx +","+targety);

//Part two - walk around the sides clockwise
         System.out.println("random start cell: "+targetx +","+targety);
     for(int targetCounter=0; targetCounter<4; targetCounter++){         
         if ((targetx==1)&&(targety==0)){targetx=0;targety=1;} //top to right
         if ((targetx==0)&&(targety==1)){targetx=-1;targety=0;} //right to bottom
         if ((targetx==-1)&&(targety==0)){targetx=0;targety=-1;} //bottom to left
         if ((targetx==0)&&(targety==-1)){targetx=1;targety=0;} //left to top
         System.out.println("next cell clockwise: "+targetx +","+targety);
     }
     System.out.println("end  *random side then walk around* here here");
     System.exit(0);
   } // main
      //jkend
```

Comment: You know that Math.random() returns a double between 0 and 1? Maybe try java.util.Random.nextInt()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My results have been that the loop stops at odd places and never with
>   abs()s different. I suspect the while() expression is wrong

```
System.out.println("abs x "+Math.abs(targetx));
System.out.println("abs y "+Math.abs(targetx));
```

Check out the variable names in those lines.

Part II: Each of your if statements changes the value of targetx and targety such that the values match the next if statement. As a result, every if statement executes and the values of targetx and targety at the end of the loop are the values set in the last if statement.

You should be using an if-else if structure. Even if the values being set in each of the if statements did not match the next if statement, you would still want to use an if-else if structure because then java wouldn't have to check all 4 if conditions every time through the loop.  With and if-else if structure, as soon as one if matches, the rest are skipped.

Comment: I conclude I made a dumb mistake. I keep telling myself not to copy- paste without immediately making the change. Maybe I need to tell myself louder. Thanks for turning an answer into a lesson. That was really good.

Comment: It happens to everybody. :)

Comment: Then in part two it seems none of the expressions result in a match. If 1,0 goes into the loop then 1,0 comes out for all three iterations. I expected that 1,0 in would match the first if() and change the vars to 0,1. Is the expression wrong? I tried targetx.equals(1) but can't use that on primitives. Thanks.

Comment: @Playing with GAS, Added answer to your next question.

Comment: Ah, brilliant. The first if *is* true and changes x,y. So then on next line it sees the changed and is not testing the original. The fact that the order means the changed values mach the next if exacerbated the problem.

Comment: I got you on the else if - I was trying to make it simpler by testing with independent ifs and ended up too clever by half. With the else if after a match it drops out without doing more testing. Thanks so much for your help on this. Now I can move on to the core problems of the assignment.

Comment: @PlayingwithGAS, Your welcome. Go ahead and click the "answered" checkmark so as to let people know that you don't need anymore help.